# Why chrome browser can not display the clipped section of div at the first time?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I want to create a 3D split-flap.

I referred the 3D Flip Box (Vertical) in w3schools web site.
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_flip_box2.

It works fine.

It is because I want to build a split-flap, so I need to cut both 'flip-box-front' and 'flip-box-back' by half.

However, I changed both "flip-box-front" and "flip-box-back"class as the following:

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.flip-box {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-box-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.flip-box:hover .flip-box-inner {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.flip-box-front, .flip-box-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-box-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
  clip-path:polygon(0% 0%,100% 0%,100% 50%,0% 50%);
}

.flip-box-back {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  clip-path:polygon(0% 50%,100% 50%,100% 100%,0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<h1>3D Flip Box (Vertical)</h1>
<h3>Hover over the box below:</h3>

<div class="flip-box">
  <div class="flip-box-inner">
    <div class="flip-box-front">
      <h2>Front Side</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-box-back">
      <h2>Back Side</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I found that the lower part (i.e. flip-box-back) does not be shown immediately when the mouse over on it at the first time in the chrome browser. It is strange it works fine after the first time.

It works fine on Firefox browser.
Is there any workaround for chrome browser?

Answer (score 0):

Use `polygon(0% 0%,100% 0%,100% 100%,0% 100%)` as your `clip-path` in both 'flip-box-front' and 'flip-box-back' class as the following:

```
.flip-box-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
  clip-path:polygon(0% 0%,100% 0%,100% 100%,0% 100%);
}

.flip-box-back {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  clip-path:polygon(0% 0%,100% 0%,100% 100%,0% 100%);
}
```

Comment: It is because I want to build a split-flap, so I need to cut both 'flip-box-front' and 'flip-box-back' by half.

Comment: Please mention the your current chrome version

Comment: Version 76.0.3809.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: My understanding is that  chrome partially supporting css clip-path property only. It may be the reason.

Comment: Well, is there any way to remove/hide the upper part of a div?